# Difference in calculated pH and the real pH of a phosphate buffer

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, aqueous-solution, analytical-chemistry, ph

I want to prepare a buffer system with $\mathrm{pH} = 7.00$ and a total concentration $c_\mathrm{tot} = \pu{0.10 mol l^-1}$ using sodium hydrogen phosphate $(\ce{Na2HPO4})$ and sodium dihydrogen phosphate $(\ce{NaH2PO4})$ salts. I am calculating the amounts to prepare a phosphate buffer as follows:

$$\ce{H2PO4- <=> HPO4^2- + H+} \qquad \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 7.20 \tag{R1}$$

$$\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log\frac{[\ce{HPO4^2-}]}{[\ce{H2PO4-}]} \tag{1}$$

$$\frac{[\ce{HPO4^2-}]}{[\ce{H2PO4-}]} = 10^{\mathrm{pH} - \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}} = 10^{7.00-7.20} \approx 0.632 \tag{2}$$

$$
\begin{align}
c_\mathrm{tot} &= [\ce{H2PO4-}] + [\ce{HPO4^2-}] \\
  &= [\ce{H2PO4-}] + [\ce{H2PO4-}]\times 0.632 \\
  &= [\ce{H2PO4-}]\times 1.632 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

$$[\ce{H2PO4-}] = \frac{c_\mathrm{tot}}{1.632} = \frac{\pu{0.10 mol l^-1}}{1.632} \approx \pu{0.061 mol l^-1}\tag{4}$$

$$[\ce{HPO4^2-}] = c_\mathrm{tot} - [\ce{H2PO4-}] = \pu{0.10 mol l^-1} - \pu{0.061 mol l^-1} = \pu{0.039 mol l^-1} \tag{5}$$

For the preparation of $V = \pu{500 ml}$ buffer solution I used the following masses of corresponding salts:

$$
\begin{align}
m(\ce{NaH2PO4}) &= [\ce{H2PO4-}]\cdot V\cdot M(\ce{NaH2PO4}) \\
  &= (\pu{0.061 mol l^-1})(\pu{0.500 l})(\pu{119.97 g mol^-1}) \\
  &\approx\pu{3.66 g} \tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
m(\ce{Na2HPO4}) &= [\ce{HPO4^2-}]\cdot V\cdot M(\ce{Na2HPO4}) \\
  &= (\pu{0.039 mol l^-1})(\pu{0.500 l})(\pu{141.97 g mol^-1}) \\
  &\approx\pu{2.77 g} \tag{7}
\end{align}
$$

When I mixed the calculated amounts, the obtained $\mathrm{pH} = 6.5$ deviated quite a lot from the desired value. I thought it was my mistake in calculations or an error when I weighed the amounts, but I repeated everything several times and still not get the $\mathrm{pH} = 7.00,$ and the value always was $6.4$ or $6.5.$

I would like to know the reason. I think if the concentration of the monobasic salt is greater than the one of the dibasic salt, the $\mathrm{pH}$ tends to decrease, but in the calculations the relation [dibasic]/[monobasic] is always less than 1 and this again causes [monobasic] > [dibasic].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flaw in your calculations is the assumption that the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ is a constant independent of concentration.  In reality, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ is a function of the [ionic strength $I$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_strength).

At infinite dilution $I = 0$ and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 7.20$ as you assumed. However at the concentration $\pu{0.10 mol l^-1}$ of phosphate buffer $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 6.81.$ See [Florida State University — Phosphate Buffers](http://www.chem.fsu.edu/chemlab/Mastering/PhosphateBuffers.htm) and the paper by Green [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01333a018)].

#### Reference

1. Green, A. A. The Preparation of Acetate and Phosphate Buffer Solutions of Known PH and Ionic Strength. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1933**, 55 (6), 2331–2336. DOI: [10.1021/ja01333a018](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01333a018).

Comment: It depends, if activity coefficients are managed explicitly or implicitly.